# Why does VS Code's terminal appear as blank?

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
About VSCode
 Version: 1.62.3 (user setup)
 Commit: ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247
 Date: 2021-11-17T08:11:14.551Z
 Electron: 13.5.2
 Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
 Node.js: 14.16.0
 V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
 OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043
```

What I see when open terminal:

[image: screenshot of blank VS Code]

I have no idea why VSCode shows like this!

It occurred after installing Ubuntu 20 on Windows WSL.
I tried to uninstall Ubuntu from my WSL but this issue still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to remove this blank terminal screen:

1. Click bottom left setting wheel
2. Go to setting > Features > terminal
3. Select Explorer kind: Integrated
4. Change inheritEnv to true.

You can also remove that by adding the below code.
-> Go to settings and search for 'Inherit Env'.
-> open Edit in settings.json and change.

**"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true**

Comment: terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true

its working....
Thanks